# Как красиво вывести данные

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица какие люди когда приходят.
В таблице данные лежат как на фото1

[image: фото1]

Как вывести как на фото2?

[image: фото2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь решаем две задачи.

Во-первых, следует в отдельном столбце `num` пронумеровать строки с людьми по каждому дню недели.

Во-вторых, создать pivot-таблицу, прогруппировав записи по столбцу `num`.

Код такой:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'понедельник' THEN name ELSE '' END) AS `понедельник`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'вторник' THEN name ELSE '' END) AS `вторник`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN day = 'среда' THEN name ELSE '' END) AS `среда`
FROM (
  SELECT 
      @row_number:=CASE
          WHEN @day_name = day THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1
      END AS num,
      @day_name:=day as day,
      name
  FROM
      test
  ORDER BY day, name
) t
GROUP BY num
```

Данное решение работает на любой версии MySQL. Для MySQL 8 оно может быть прооптимизировано.

Рабочий пример - на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34d5bfa/26)